# Flex Gridlayout with flex-direction row and different heights of row

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need a flex grid, where each grid cell has equal width, after every second cell it should wrap. But some cells should have full width. So far no problem.

But I want some of these cells have a fixed height.

In my example I want the blue background to be hidden and filled by the cells below the first one. Is this possible without adding more html tags?

The outcome should look like the second box, but without the additional html tag.

```css
.flex-container {  
  background-color: blue;
  -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: red 5px solid;
}

.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  width: 50%;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  border: green 1px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flex-item:first-child {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

.flex-container2 {  
  background-color: blue;
  -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: red 5px solid;
}

.flex-item2 {
  background: tomato;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  border: green 1px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 50px;
}

.additional-flex-container {
 -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.additional-flex-container .flex-item2 {
  background: tomato;
  width: 50%;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  border: green 1px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item">2</div>
  <div class="flex-item">3</div>
  <div class="flex-item">4</div>
  <div class="flex-item">5</div>
</div>

<hr/>

<div class="flex-container2">
  <div class="flex-item2">1</div>
  <div class="additional-flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item2">2</div>
    <div class="flex-item2">3</div>
    <div class="flex-item2">4</div>
    <div class="flex-item2">5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried http://flexboxgrid.com/ ?

Comment: AN image of how this is supposed to look, perhaps with 9 boxes would be useful becuase I can't quite envisage this working with just one containing element . "Some" elements will have greater height. Is this a fixed value for all of them are are you attempting a *masonry* scenario.

Comment: I added a second box to show the desired outcome.

Comment: No...I don't think you can do that with a single wrapper (at least not as far as I know). Your second 'solution' is the one I think you'd have to use. *Maybe* with `flex-direction:column` but that wouldn't have the same order and I'm still not sure it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only possibility I found was to calculate the height of all items. It is not as flexible as I want it, but I can play around at least with some additional classes.

```css
.flex-container {  
  background-color: blue;
  -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: red 5px solid;
}

.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  width: 50%;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  border: green 1px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: calc((100% - 50px) / 2);
}

.flex-item:first-child {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item">2</div>
  <div class="flex-item">3</div>
  <div class="flex-item">4</div>
  <div class="flex-item">5</div>
</div>
```